# On reposting a good answer from a duplicate question

Tags: discussion, answers, exact-duplicates

I'm talking about [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3339865). This question is closed as a duplicate. An user commented, under an answer, that they think this answer is the best solution and want the author to repost the answer to the original question.
Personally, I think reposting an answer does not contribute much to the community because visitors of the original question can see the linked question and hence visit the duplicate question and its answers.
What are your opinions? Should the author repost the answer? Would this kind of action considered as rep-farming?

Comment: When/if the duplicate gets deleted, visitors may not be able to see it. Even if they can see it, they may be discouraged from doing so by the extra work involved in clicking (any barrier, however small, acts to discourage) and by the very fact that the question has been closed as a duplicate.

Comment: If you're concerned about rep-farming, it seems simple enough to mark it as a Community Wiki post. (Preferably with a note stating where the post came from and why it's CW.) You get to contribute the answer and don't have to contend with what you may feel is unwarranted rep.

Comment: I think the one who commented actually meant to post (delete your actual answer (which is not even possible) and move it to the original question, for my understanding), not to repost it, which just brings a duplicate answer. I encountered the same thing a few days ago and what I did was to let a moderator know about it (afterwards the posts got merged).

Comment: As mentioned in the previous comment, [merging](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/tags/merging/info) could be a good solution in such situations, if it is possible. (In this specific case, I suppose that the moderators will notice your post on meta and check whether searching is a suitable solution here.)

Comment: I have added some background to the [original question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2136298/515527) since it was missing, hopefully no one minds (OP is away for more than two years anyway) and maybe now it will be a better fit for merging.

Comment: I just had a similar experience where I found the answer to my post on another post. I just added at the bottom of my question that "I found the answer here:" then pasted the link there.