# Where to Place Answer to a Duplicate Question

Tags: discussion, answers, exact-duplicates

I recently posted [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4261369/give-a-combinatorial-proof-for-the-expression-sum-k-0n-1-2k-2n-1/4261610#4261610) to a question marked as a duplicate.  I did check first that my approach had not previously been taken.  Should I delete my answer and transplant the analysis as an answer to the previous question?

Comment: If you answer question then find out that it is a duplicate, but you feel that your answer has not been posted before, then please delete the original answer and repost it to the duplicate question.  Generally speaking, consolidation is better.

Comment: @XanderHenderson Okay, will do.

Comment: @XanderHenderson why not promote your comment to an answer proper? :)

Comment: @TheAmplitwist Because I am nigh certain that this question has been asked on meta before, but I don't have the time right now to look for a duplicate target.

Comment: There is this question: [On reposting a good answer from a duplicate question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/30634). (The question is not the same - but I'd still consider it related. It has no answer - but there is at least some discussion in the comments.)

Comment: @MartinSleziak I was about to post that same link. :) As you say, it’s related, but also not answered.

Comment: @XanderHenderson I couldn’t find any proper duplicate in my searches. Even if it has been answered somewhere before, it’s good to have a few searchable duplicates lying around. I encourage you once more to post your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Just as [Xander Handerson](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/users/468350/xander-henderson) wrote in this question comments

> If you answer question then find out that it is a duplicate, but you feel that your answer has not been posted before, then please delete the original answer and repost it to the duplicate question.

Comment: Yes, I did exactly that as soon as I got Xander Henderson's comment.

Comment: Then its perfectly fine @user2661923